# MuleESB flow, why do I get two files outputted?

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I'm trying to get one record from MongoDB and put it into a file, but I get two files, why is that? I thought that these would execute in a sequence and each step in the flow would take the data from the previous step, am I wrong?

```
<flow name="test1Flow2" doc:name="test1Flow2">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP"/>
<mongo:find-one-object
    config-ref="Mongo_DB" collection="my_collection" doc:name="Mongo DB"
    query-ref="#[string:{ }]" >
</mongo:find-one-object>
  <mongo:dbobject-to-json doc:name="Mongo DB"/>
 <file:outbound-endpoint path="/somewhere" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Mongo DB"/>
</flow>
```

I go to this URL to trigger its execution.

```
http://localhost:8081/
```

Thanks, Philip

Comment: If you step debug, what's the output of `mongo:find-one-object` and `dbobject-to-json`? What processor(s) get executed several times? Also: are you sure the `http:inbound-endpoint` should be `request-response`: do you really want to return the queried JSON object back to the caller on top of writing it to the file?

Comment: Anton is most certainly right. My question regarding the appropriateness of `request-response` remains standing.

Comment: Hi yes all I want to be able to do is have this flow execute, but I couldn't work out how to get the flow to execute. So I added the http request response so I could trigger the flow from the browser. Is there some other way the flow could execute?

Comment: Even with `one-way` you'll be able to execute from the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting a path attribute for the http inbound endpoint, you are quite likely experiencing a favicon.ico request sent by your browser along with the http request you actually want to do.