# How to establish a loop using Mule ESB? a process which takes records from MongoDB and saves them to file

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I'm trying to establish a loop using Mule ESB, that is I want to consume one record from MongoDB and then save it to file. Then I want this to repeat while there are records in MongoDB.

Whenever a new record is added to MongoDB I want it to consume that record and save it to file.

I can create a flow to do this once, but I don't see how the flow can be triggered to happen all the time while there are records in MongoDB. This should just continue to happen all the time while records are in MongoDb and if a new record is added to MongoDb then it should consume that.

Can someone point me to an example?

[MuleESB flow, why do I get two files outputted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22072121/muleesb-flow-why-do-i-get-two-files-outputted)

Comment: What's your current Mule configuration file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure a watermark and poll the datasource. Check out this blog for details - http://blogs.mulesoft.org/data-synchronizing-made-easy-with-mule-watermarks/